# Entity Framework: Map join tables

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following model:

[image]

I want to expose a member on "intallations" that give me a list of "modules" based on the join table "installation_modules", how can I do that ?

I want to be able to write

```
installations.Modules.Something()
```

Without having to use the join table in my code.

I also want to map "installation_type" directly on the installation, is it possible ? If yes how ?

Comment: In Code First it's quite easy. But looks like you are using edmx? According to [this post](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/entity-framework-for-beginners-creating-a-database-first-model/), it should be possible. May be [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713299.aspx) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework will automatically manage the many-many relationship for you, but usually the `installation_modules` table should be having just two columns, `installation_id` and `module_id` which will be the composite primary key instead of a separate primary key. So `Installation` model/class will have `public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules {get; set;}` and the `Module` class will have `public virtual ICollection<Installation> Installations {get; set;}`navigational properties for easy accessing of entities.

> I also want to map "installation_type" directly on the installation, is it possible ? If yes how ?

Yes, it is possible. You can have a navigational property for `InstallationType` in your `Installation` entity for this.

```
public class Installation
{
 //....other properties

 [Column("installation_type_id")]
 public int InstallationTypeId {get; set;}

 [ForeignKey("InstallationTypeId")]
 public virtual InstallationType InstallationType{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the id on the join table and it's working "out of the box" when I update my model, I now have a collection of modules on my installation entity :) Hopefully I'm still in the design of the db with db-first approach.
For the second question my question wasn't clear enough I think, what I want is the property "type" of the entity "InstallationType" directly mapped on my "installation" entity

Comment: _what I want is the property "type" of the entity "InstallationType" directly mapped on my "installation" entity_ - this is accessible via the navigational property. But if you need that type property directly, then one workaround is to have a property `[NotMapped]public string InstType { get {return this.InstallationType?.Type }}`